# css: how to display a radiobuttonlist horizontally?

Tags: html, css

How can I align a radiobuttonlist horizontally? This one is to capture a gender value , male/female. I want to keep the name input css the same. This is the html:

```
<label for="temp">Gender</label>

<label for="one">Male</label>
<input type="radio" id="one" name="first_item" value="1" />

<label for="two">Female</label>
<input type="radio" id="one" name="first_item" value="2" />
```

The css:

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    background-color: #2196f3;
    padding: 10px;
}

.left-griditem {
}

input,
label {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/bertie2017/pen/WgdGBO). Currently the buttons are in a vertical position.

Comment: `input,label {display: inline-block;}label:nth-child(3) {display: block;}` try this. but you have to group label and input under a div, then only you can achieve perfection. `id="one"` is duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only the radio buttons, add this style:

```
#genderArea input, #genderArea label{
    display: inline;
}
```

and use this HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="left-griditem">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name">

        <label for="temp">Gender</label>

        <span id="genderArea">
        <label for="one">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" id="one" name="first_item" value="1" />
            <br>
        <label for="two">Female</label>
        <input type="radio" id="one" name="first_item" value="2" />
        </span>

    </div>
    <div class="right-griditem">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code using table, tr and td tags

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="one">Male</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="one" name="first_item" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td style="widht:20px;"></td>
    <td>
      <label for="two">Female</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="one" name="first_item" value="2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This approach gives you the flexibility to put controls, the way you want

Comment: You are suggesting tables for layout purposes? Seriously? Is it 1998 again?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap particular row which you want to make under a div/ a tag.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  background-color: #2196f3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left-griditem {}

input,
label {
  display: inline-block;
}

div.item>label:first-child {
  width: 70px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.item:first-child>input,
div.item:first-child>label {
  display: block
}

body {
  background: hsl(221, 64%, 24%);
  color: hsl(235, 9%, 39%);
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 2rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
}

div {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1vw 2vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="left-griditem">
    <div class="item">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <label for="temp">Gender</label>
      <label for="one">Male</label>
      <input type="radio" id="one" name="first_item" value="1" />
      <label for="two">Female</label>
      <input type="radio" id="two" name="first_item" value="2" />
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="right-griditem">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The gender line looks good but I dont want the Name style inline

Comment: @bierhier, you can achieve anything by using `display: block/inline-block`, for respective `nth-child(n)` element. If you want name style should be block, give `div.item:first-child > input, div.item:first-child > label { display: block }`. I have changed. But you have to do hit and trial and check references of selectors of css and fix.

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
input,
label {
    display: block;
}
```

To this:

```
input,
label {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Just want the radiobuttons inline not the rest